# Is [validating] a valid synonym of [validation]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validating) tag currently has 111 questions (and no tag wiki), whilst the [validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validation) tag currently has 51,366 questions. Given the broad definition of the latter tag, it seems quite clear that the former should be a synonym of it.

The [suggested synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/validation/synonyms) already shows <strike>3</strike> 4 votes for [validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/validating), so it only needs a little nudge from someone with the necessary reputation/answer score.

Comment: The synonym has already been added by now (that was a quick request!)

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth. I feel validated.

Comment: It is not a synonym, it is the name of a .NET event.  Well, was.  I think I am the top answerer in the tag with a score of 74.  Well, was.

Comment: @HansPassant. In that case, shouldn't there be a [.net-validating] tag if the [.net] / [validation] combo isn't sufficient? And why was there no tag-excerpt or tag-wiki for [validating] if it was intended to be so specific? I certainly saw quite a few questions using the [validating] tag that weren't relevant to .net.

Comment: For the past 8 years, users that had trouble with their Validating event handler never needed a custom tag to find me.  It is not how tags work, the machine pays attention to all tags on a question.  I blissfully never get [validation] questions.  I won't get [validating] questions anymore either, yay.

Comment: @HansPassant. I take it that there is nothing that can now be done to reverse the process? I'm sorry you didn't get the opportunity to stop this happening. I suggested this synonym about a year ago, and it already had three upvotes before I asked about it here.

Comment: I don't know what it takes to reverse this, afaik there is no mechanism to undo synonym votes.  Consider flagging a moderator on this question.

Comment: @HansPassant. I have flagged this question for moderator attention as you suggested. From what I have now read on the subject, it should be relatively straightforward for a mod to undo a tag synonym (as opposed to a merge).

Comment: This synonym request has received [validation].

Comment: @HansPassant That passive aggressive behavior does not suit you ;) OP is right, if the tag has a double meaning (or is used wrong a lot) there should be a `[.net-validating]`